# C# Set amount of characters taken by a string

Tags: c#, formatting

So lets say i got a digit 592 but i always want it taking up the space of 6 characters with 3 white space characters being in front of the 592. How would this be done?

So the example output would be "   592"

But this should work if the string is lets say 82, so then requiring four white spaces such as "    82"

Comment: What if your number is having 7 or more digits?

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
"592".PadLeft(6, ' ');
```

Answer will be `"   593"`.

If you do

```
"82".PadLeft(6, ' ');
```

Answer will be `"    82"`.

6 is the length of final string which in your case will always be 6.

Comment: Sorry edited original question to add, But this should work if the string is lets say 82, so then requiring four white spaces. So ensuring that it will take up 6 characters no matter the digit placed inside?

Comment: This is the simplest way, and clean as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following works :

```
        int x = 182;
        string y = x.ToString();
        int numberOfSpaces = 6 - y.Length;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append(new string(' ', numberOfSpaces));
        str.Append(y);
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
```